# How to search for data in PyMongo?

Tags: python, pymongo

I am wondering how to search for some data in a collection and get the rest of the data for the document in PyMongo (the python module for MongoDB). For example, I have a collection called Users inside a database called WindowsApp. How do I search for a user like this: `{"username":"CrispyBacon"}` and request to get the `{"password"}` field in the document. So what I am looking for is to search for this:  `{"username":"CrispyBacon"}` and get the response like this: `{"password":"ItsYummy321"}` if the document said this: `{"username":"CrispyBacon", "password":"ItsYummy321"}`. Here is what I'm doing with it: https://pastebin.com/pE3AKNKE  How do I get this to tell me just the value for `{"password"}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use projection to ask MongoDB to return only desired fields. According to [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), it must look like this in PyMongo:

```py
password = coll.find_one({"username":username}, {"password": 1, "_id": 0})
```

Note that `_id` field is always included in result unless you explicitly tell you don't want it to be returned.

Edit: If you want only the password string, you don't need projection. Just get value of `password` key from returned dictionary:

```py
password = coll.find_one({"username":username})["password"]
```

Comment: I tried it out and it responds: `{"password":"ItsYummy321"}` That's great but can I make it give me just `ItsYummy321`?

Comment: @MangoCoder360 All you must do is get the value from returned dictionary. I'll edit my answer to fulfill this.

Comment: That gives me a error: `TypeError: index 'password' cannot be applied to Cursor instances` when I do `print(password)` under your code.

Comment: Ah, `find()` returns a cursor since you may have numerous objects to be returned. This is why you can't call `["password"]` on it. Using `find_one` would solve this error and returns a dictionary. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer! You need to iterate the received variable because it is a Cursor type that needs to be iterated. Then you can grab the value you want by key. For example:

```
    username = easygui.enterbox("Enter your username:")
    password = easygui.enterbox("Enter your password:")
    getData = coll.find({"username":username}, {"password": 1, "_id": 0})
    for i in getData: data = i
    print(data["password"])
```